# Nested array value not showing in the innerHTML table td section in angular?

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I have an dynamic innerHTML in which we have to show the dynamic data but issue is that every value is visible but table td values not showing its showing undefined value,can anybody help how to get inside td tag?

```js
viewDynamicHTML(){
   return `<div class="form-tab"  id="OrderDetailsPage">
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-5"> 
       <b>PO#</b>:<p>${this.salesOrderModel.CustomerRefNo}</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-5" style="float:right;"> 
       <b>SO#</b>:<p>${this.salesOrderModel.ERPSalesOrderKey}</p>
     </div>
   </div> 
   </div>  
    <table class="table" border="1"  cellspacing="5"  cellpadding="5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th  width="50%">Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableBody">
          ${this.renderTableTd()}
        </tbody>
    </table>
  }

  renderTableTd(){
      const tableData =  this.salesOrderModel.SalesOrderItemList.map((data)=>{
        return (
          `<tr>
              <td>${data.ERPItemKey}</td>
              <td>${data.ItemName}</td>
              <td>${data.Quantity}</td>
              <td>${data.QuantityUnit}</td>
              <td>${data.UnitPrice}</td>
              <td>${data.UnitPrice * data.Quantity}</td>
          </tr>`
        );
      })
  }
```

```html
FieldName: "<div class=\"form-tab\"  id=\"OrderDetailsPage\">\n    <div class=\"print-area\">\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <div class=\"col-md-12\"><span class=\"page-name\">Web Order</span></div>\n          <div class=\"col-md-12\"> <div class=\"divider\"></div><br> </div>\n        </div>\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <div class=\"col-md-12\">\n            <div class=\"logo-img\">                \n              <img *ngIf=\"${this.businessLogoUrl} && ${this.businessLogoUrl} != '\" src=\"${this.businessLogoUrl}\" />\n            \n          </div>\n          <div class=\"business-name\"> ${this.tenantName}</div><br>\n            <div class=\"form-group\" style=\"margin-left: 70px;\">  \n              <div class=\"col-md-12\">\n                ${this.salesOrderModel.BusinessAddress}    \n              </div>\n          </div>\n            <div class=\"form-group\" style=\"margin-left: 70px;\">\n              <div class=\"col-md-12\">  \n                ${this.salesOrderModel.BusinessContactNo}\n              </div>  \n          </div>\n          </div>\n        </div>  <hr>\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <div class=\"col-md-12\"></div>\n        </div>\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <div class=\"col-md-5\" style=\"float:right;\">\n            <b>Ship To</b>\n            :${this.salesOrderModel.CustomerName}<span *ngIf=\"${this.salesOrderModel.ShipToKey}\">,${this.salesOrderModel.ShipToKey}</span>\n            <p>${this.salesOrderModel.ShipToAddress}</p>\n          </div>\n          <div class=\"col-md-5\" >\n            <b>Bill To</b>:${this.salesOrderModel.CustomerName}<p>${this.salesOrderModel.BillToAddress }</p>\n          </div>\n        </div>\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <div class=\"col-md-12\"></div>\n        </div>\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <div class=\"col-md-5\">\n            <b>PO#</b>:<p>${this.salesOrderModel.CustomerRefNo}</p>\n          </div>\n          <div class=\"col-md-5\" style=\"float:right;\">\n            <b>SO#</b>:<p>${this.salesOrderModel.ERPSalesOrderKey}</p>\n          </div>\n        </div>\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <div class=\"col-md-12\"></div>\n        </div>\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <div class=\"col-md-5\">\n            <b>Order Date</b>:<p>${this.salesOrderModel.PostingDate}</p>\n          </div>\n          <div class=\"col-md-5\" style=\"float:right;\">\n            <b>Requested Date</b>:<p>${this.salesOrderModel.DeliveryDate}</p>\n          </div>\n        </div>  \n        <table class=\"table\" border=\"1\"  cellspacing=\"5\"  cellpadding=\"5\">\n          <thead>\n            <tr>\n              <th>Item</th>\n              <th  width=\"50%\">Description</th>\n              <th>Quantity</th>\n              <th>Unit</th>\n              <th>Price</th>\n              <th>Total</th>\n            </tr>\n          </thead>\n          <tbody id=\"tableBody\">\n            ${this.renderDynamicColoumsValue()}\n          </tbody>\n        </table>\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <div class=\"col-md-12\"></div>\n        </div>\n        <hr>\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <div class=\"col-md-4\" *ngIf=\"${this.totalAmount>0}\">\n            <b>Total Quantity</b>: <p>${this.totalQuantity}</p>\n          </div>\n          <div class=\"col-md-4\" style=\"float:right;\" *ngIf=\"${this.totalAmount>0}\">\n            <b>Total Amount</b>:<p>${this.totalAmount}</p>\n          </div>\n        </div>\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <div class=\"col-md-12\"> <span class=\"sub-title\"><h3>Remarks</h3></span></div>\n        </div>\n        <div class=\"form-group\">\n          <div class=\"col-md-12\">\n            ${this.salesOrderModel.Remarks}\n          </div>\n        </div>\n      </div>\n    </div>\n"
```

Comment: did you forget to put a ` after </table> ? in your snippet it seems you did, so the function would just be rendered as an HTML string?

Comment: In the renderTableTd function it looks like your appointing you const ```tableData``` to a string value, and then do nothing... Return the const value in the function, and it should work

Comment: @JamesD sir can you please update my fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appointing your constant, but then you're not returning it. At the moment the `renderTableTd()` has a return type of void. The IDE would've helped you if you would mention the return type you expected.

```
  renderTableTd(){
      const tableData =  this.salesOrderModel.SalesOrderItemList.map((data)=>{
        return (
          `<tr>
              <td>${data.ERPItemKey}</td>
              <td>${data.ItemName}</td>
              <td>${data.Quantity}</td>
              <td>${data.QuantityUnit}</td>
              <td>${data.UnitPrice}</td>
              <td>${data.UnitPrice * data.Quantity}</td>
          </tr>`
        );
      });
      return tableData; // <---try this
  }
```

Comment: sir today i returned innerHTML from API side but its not render our data its showing same string like   -${this.salesOrderModel.BusinessAddress}.can you tell m why its not working that case. check my udpated fiddle?

Comment: in the fiddle ```${this.businessLogoUrl} != '\" src=\"${this.businessLogoUrl}\" ``` is missing a '

Comment: it's easier to just make a new question because you are now merging 2 separate questions into one and changing the required answer, which is not the way to work with StackOverflow. An edit to improve your question is okay, a new separate question is not.

Comment: ok  will update new question